# Parse file with multiple JSON objects in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to parse a file that contains multiple JSON objects that are not enclosed in an array and are separated only by a line break. The file has the following schema:

```
{"id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
{"id":2,"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Smith"}
```

As far as I know, the standard approach using `json.load()` doesn't work here, because the objects are not enclosed in an array. So is there an elegant way to parse such a file in Python without modifying it?

Comment: Is every json object guaranteed to be on a single line?

Comment: @Holloway Yes, that is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every json object is on its own line, you should be able to do something like

```
with open('/path/to/file') as data:
    objects = [json.loads(line) for line in data]
```